# How to change speed based on gravity, and angle of movement

Tags: javascript, html, physics

I am making a simple project where a dot is orbiting another dot. I could not find a mathematical formula to change the speed of the dot based on its movement direction proportional to the gravity. I have not taken physics yet so all of this is still very hard to me.

```js
var c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.width = window.innerWidth;
c.height = window.innerHeight;
c.style = "position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; background-color: black;";
document.body.appendChild(c);
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var shipX = 50;
var shipY = 0;
var moveDir = 0;
var speed = 8;
var halfX = window.innerWidth/2;
var halfY = window.innerHeight/2;
var gravSpeed = 0.7;


function pixelOn(x,y){
 ctx.fillStyle = "white";
  ctx.fillRect(x,y,2,2);
}

function draw(){
  pixelOn(halfX,halfY);
    pixelOn(shipX+halfX,halfY-shipY);
    shipX += Math.sin(moveDir*Math.PI/180)*speed;
    shipY += Math.cos(moveDir*Math.PI/180)*speed;
    var gravDir = Math.atan2(-shipX,-shipY);
    var nd = Math.atan2(Math.sin(moveDir*Math.PI/180-gravDir), Math.cos(moveDir*Math.PI/180-gravDir))*180/Math.PI;
    moveDir -= nd/(speed/gravSpeed);
    //change speed on movement direction here

}

setInterval(function(){
 draw();
},50);
```

Comment: Advice: 1) use vectors instead of angles, much easier to work with; 2) if the speed increases then the orbital radius must decrease; 3) (optional) this method of incrementation (called Euler integration) produces large errors very quickly; if you want you can look into *Runge-Kutta* methods.

Comment: It will be very difficult to get this working without a grasp of basic physics. What information do you have and what information do you want to calculate? Are you comfortable with vectors? How about calculus?